# how to reach database with javascript

Tags: javascript, database

I want to show some informations on site from database. But I know there is no way to connect to database with native javascript. And I read something about this is not a good method.

So I really curious about how developers show informations on sites from database? For example member name? It's in somewhere in the database. Site is coded with javascript. How can javascript reach member name info?

Comment: Its basically using ajax.

Comment: Use AJAX to send a HTTP request to some form of backend server  (PHP, Node.js, Ruby, etc...) and then display the returned result.

Comment: is this the most common method?

Answer (score 0):

They use AJAX to send request to the back-end. 
For example, javascript may ask special php script to return mebmer's name by id.

```
$.get( "sitename.com/script.php", {id: 125},
     function( data ) {
         alert( "The name is "+data );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a scripting language. There is PHP, C#, ColdFusion, and many more options. You will probably want to use PHP because it's free, and it is included on most hosting services, but check with your host to see what they support.

Comment: Since when is C# a scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct connecting to a database from client-side JavaScript (I say client-side JavaScript because we now have node.js that is server-sider JavaScript) is a bad idea because you would need to send (expose) your connection information to the client; e.g. the username, password, database name, and DBMS engine would all be exposed to anyone that visited your site.

Most people that fetch information from a database in JavaScript code do so by sending AJAX (asynchronous GET, POST, etc. HTTP requests) to some server-side code that handles CRUD with the database.  You can expose server-side code as a web-service, API, or have POST/GET methods in your server-side project that return information (usually in JSON or XML).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ajax call to a file written on php for example that exist on you server, for example look at the following code

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

//send query to bbdd (information is in the input with id="information")
//and sended when pressed the button with id="btn-send"
$(function(){
    $("#btn-send").click(function() {
        var url = "file_that_search.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#information").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#html").html(data);//paste the data to the browser
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
})
</script>
```

then the file "file_that_search.php" has the retrieved data from the BBDD making something like

```
$search= "ID=" . $_POST['consult'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE ".$search;
```